# asyncTask from one activity running in another activity android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im just wondering what would be the best and possibly easiest way to do this. I have two activites LoginAcitivty and Main Activity.

Ive coded an AsyncTask in my MainActivity as an inner class which sends updates to a web service. When i click the logout button of the MainActivity this returns the app to the Login Activity. Is it possible to still run the ASyncTask even though there is a different activity running or is there another way to do something like this?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Asynctask is tied to the "Entity" that created it, in your case it would be the MainActivity, so it will not survive the destroy of your activity (I trust you call the finis() method of the main activity once the user logs out)
What you can do is use a service that runs in background and use the async task to poll your server:

The service shall look like this:

```
 public class PollService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();    
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
      (new PollAsyncTask(this)).execute();
    }

    //callback used to retrieve the result from the asynctask
    void callBack(String result) {
      //here is your logic, taking the result back from the async task
      //eventually re-run the asynctask
      (new PollAsyncTask(this)).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

The AsyncTask shall look like this:

```
 private class PollAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private PollService caller;
    PollAsyncTask(PollService caller) {
         this.caller = caller;
    } 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do your polling here and return something meaningful to the service,
        return SOMETHING_REFERRING_TO_THE_1_OF_3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Give the result back to the caller:
        this.caller.callBack(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {//nothing special here}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {//nothing special here}

  }
```

That way your async task will poll your server whatever activity is currently in foreground.
The service shall be started by your first activity when it is run the first time (i.e. in the **onCreate** method):

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     if (savedInstanceState==null) {//only the first time
          Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
          serviceIntent.setAction("com.yourcompany....PollService");
          startService(serviceIntent);
     }

 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a service already which gets GPS locations for the MainActivity would this still be considered a good option if I were to have that service and another just for running the polling?

Comment: IMHO yes it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, you have an inner Class in your MainActivity.
So just make your AsyncTask in a separate Class and you can call it from both Activites.

Like: `new YourAsyncTask().execute();`

Greetings.

Comment: Yes its in an inner class as there are a couple of UI elements run within the Async. Was wondering if there was a way to execute from the inner class as I will need to rethink the UI threads that are used from the Async within the MainActivity?

Comment: I suggest you to redesign how are you dealing with that UI elements. Let it simple. Use the AsyncTask only for what must be done in another thread. Then create a public method in your Activity for doing the UI stuff. Now you can call the AsyncTask from both Activities. Pass in the constructor a reference of the activity and save it on a global variable `private Activity activity`. In `onPostExecute()` do: `if(activity instanceof YourActivityThatDealsWithUI) activity.yourMethodForUI();`

Comment: I set it up the way shown below and this allowed me to rejig my code to remove the UI elements from the AysncTask and back into the Activity. It now works the way i wanted to! Thanks for your input though :)

Comment: Oh nice, glad you got it anyway =)